# Remove \" escape characters from string for XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, string, xml-parsing

I am creating an XmlReader from a string. This string contains an XML feed in string format.

A snippet of that XML in the string is:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<menu>
    <menuitem name=\"Tools\">
    </menuitem>
</menu>
```

So when the line below is executed:

```
XmlReader myXmlReader = XmlReader.Create(myInputString);
```

This error is generated:

```
Illegal characters in path.
```

The issue is because of escape characters (`\"`) in the string. How can I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every word of your question is wrong.

You're seeing `\` characters because the debugger displays strings as valid string literals.
The string itself is fine.  If you print it to the console, or use the Text Visualizer, you'll see the string's raw value.

`XmlReader.Create()` is throwing an exception because it takes a path to a file, not a string of source.
To parse a string of XML source, create a new `StringReader` from that string and pass that instead.

---

Finally, `XmlReader` is an extremely annoying API.
You should use LINQ to XML instead; simply call `XElement.Parse()`.

Comment: Oops, haven't paid attention to InputUri as an argument for XmlReader. I have inherited this code, so trying to keep the changes to a minimum. Thanks for the suggestion. It works.

Comment: @SLaks "Every word of your question is wrong."  You didn't need to say that.